# Unity: Why is the animation not playing on entering trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have two game objects one with box collider (say Tiger), the other with box collider set to Is Trigger(say Horse). I want my animation "hit" to play when the Tiger game object stays in trigger, and when it exits trigger I want it to resume playing the "idle" animation. I set up two parameter also named "hit" and "idle" as trigger. But none of the animations are playing. Can anyone help, please?

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class newAttack : MonoBehaviour {

        public GameObject tiger;
        int hitHash = Animator.StringToHash("hit");
        int exitHash = Animator.StringToHash("idle");

       Animator myAnimation;

        private void Start()
        {
            myAnimation = GetComponent<Animator>();

        }


        void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
        {
            Debug.Log("Inside Trigger");
            myAnimation.SetTrigger(hitHash);
        }



        private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
        {
             Debug.Log("Exit Trigger");
             myAnimation.SetTrigger(exitHash);         
        }

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do yous objects have a RigidBody? Is the Debug being called?

Comment: you should use OnTriggerEnter instead of Stay. or use a boolean instead of trigger otherwise. BTW there are hundreds of things that could go wrong here, if you provide more of your project (animation-related) we could help better.

Comment: Having an image of the animator window would help us understand the problem. It could be that you have "any state" connecting to the "hit_anim" through "hit" and because of this, it'd "Stay" on the first frame so long as the objects are colliding. Would you be able to provide us with the animator window or a diagram of it?

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge , Yes my tiger object has a RigidBody but my horse which Is Trigger does not have a RigidBody. I know that for triggers u need RigidBody with a BoxCollider, the other should be a BoxCollider checked as Is Trigger.

Comment: @Bijan Iam using the free asset "Golden Tiger 1.0" from the unity asset store. The horse asset was free but is deprecated now.

Comment: @Alox I do not know how to add image in the comments.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FYCZFT_26WATKnMlsgmFDThvM1efXOem/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gq0VvbvRK3V5u78WI_VwBc9HCI_HAok7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i have share above screen shots of the inspector and my animation controller.

Comment: from the last image it is clear that the transitions for hit and exit are missing. these states are loose in the state machine and there is no way a trigger can start a  transition to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've not setup you animator properly. For parameters to work (e.g bool enter) you have to make transitions from idle to hit (condition: enter true) and from hit to idle (condition: enter false). Then use script to toggle that condition on trigger stay and exit.

Comment: @comhonia Thank you, using the bool helped me. I removed the trigger parameters and called the play method of the animator instead, based on the boolean parameter. It worked.

Comment: glad I could help